# Protecting floor from heavy furniture

Tags: shelving, laminate-floor

I am looking to set up a metal shelving unit in a room that has laminate flooring. The shelving unit weighs around 150 pounds with a 2' by 8' footprint. I estimate around 300 lbs of added weight on the shelves once everything is set up.

My current idea is 2 1/2" sheets of plywood side by side with 4 furniture sliders on each

I do not know the brand/type of laminate, it was installed quite a while ago prior to my move in. It is only slightly elevated above the concrete foundation level, so it may or may not even have batting underneath.

Would this method hold up appropriately under typical conditions, without causing undue damage to the flooring?

If not, what would be a better method?

```
Stock photo shelving unit in question
```

[image: SafeRack Shelf 2'D x 8'W x 7'T]

Comment: Are the shelves resting on the floor at 4 or 6 points, or are the entire lengths of the bottom beams resting on the floor? Often these shelves have screw adjustable foot-pads. Do these shelves have that or something like it? If is is resting at points, 3" by 3" plywood squares or discs under each contact point is all that is needed. You wouldn't need sheets. If there is clearance, then furniture slides would do.

Comment: @JimStewart as near as I can tell from the available information/photos, it is just a 4 point feet from the rails.